# How do you check the ASP.NET sessionsState mode on a web server?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, configuration-files

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web application that doesn't specify the sessionState mode in any of its web.config files.

This application is running on my company's web server, which I have very limited access to. Is there any way I can check which sessionState mode my web application is running in?

I am aware that 'InProc' is the default sessionState mode in ASP.NET. But I uncertain if anyone has overwritten the root config files (machine.config or root web.config, etc) on the company's web server. Note that I don't have direct access to the server, so I need write a list of places/files to try. And obviously, I can't put in any test code in there to find out.

I also tried search in the config files where the default 'InProc' mode is specified, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of paths to check?

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Server-level configuration is stored in the following configuration files:

- Machine.config. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.
- Root Web.config for the .NET Framework. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.
- ApplicationHost.config. This file is located in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config.

And finally you would want to check the Web.config of your application.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)